# Service is run once... then never again

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I created my app as I wanted a widget to display some status text on my home screen. Upon adding the widget to to home screen it updates to never update again... As a workaround I've added click event to the widget, so the click triggers the update of the widget - but that also dies, in order to fix that I have to open the application, go to my home screen en tap the widget and it will update. After a couple of minutes it does not respond to clicks again. And it never updates the widget by the set interval (updatePeriodMillis).

I've not put my app in the list of application that the OS will sleep.

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: You can try to check if the service has  been killed.

Comment: Can you show the code where you launching the Service? it could be that the Service is bound to the Application / Activity and is being killed.